# rvm install fails with or without rvmrc

Tags: rvm

I'm using rvmrc with the following text:

```
rvm_path=/local/rvm
```

(on Ubuntu 11.10) but trying to install gives an obscure error:

```
$ bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
Successfully checked out branch ''
Current branch master is up to date.
Successfully pulled (rebased) from origin 
: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Trying to install without rvmrc also failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was that the git configuration for auto-converting line endings was not set correctly which prevented any installation from working. It had nothing to do with using rvmrc settings.

The fix for this is simple (and comes straight from the github help page):

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

[Line endings are important](http://help.github.com/line-endings/) in linux and by forgetting that setting, everything the rvm-install script was pulling from github had \r\n endings.  I made that change so long ago on my work machine, I didn't even remember it -- but it was not set on my home system.

I'll leave it up in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have *no* need at all to set $rvm_path. You're using a multi-user install. Please follow the explicit instructions for the Multi-User install at https://rvm.io and remove any existing installations, remove /etc/rvmrc, /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh, and $HOME/.rvmrc. Comment out any RVM sourcing lines in your .bash_profile, and .bashrc and log out of the machine then back in. Then reinstall correctly. Setting the rvm_path has never been a requirement of the installer UNLESS you already have a Multi-User working installation in place, and you want to attempt to use a per-user install with it. THEN you would preset the $rvm_path to $HOME/.rvm in your *own* $HOME/.rvmrc, log out then back in and then attempt the install again. *BUT*, that is not a supported installation type. Which is why 99.999% of users will *not* need to set rvm_path at all.

Comment: No, I know exactly what I want.  Please don't assume.  I want a single user install that does not live in my home directory (since at work that is on a network mount and would be incompatible with other systems that share it (macos, linux)).  As a rule I do not install gems/ruby/rvm or any other dev environment into root dirs because I typically use MANY different versions at the same time (i.e. stage and prod)  These versions need to be isolated so I can easily track down dependency violations.  The setup I describe works perfectly at work which was installed a couple months ago.

Comment: Well, just because this is what you *want* doesn't mean you're doing it *right*. And you're not. Either follow what we've described for installation type and methodology or use something else. RVM provides exactly what you state you want and does so quite well. Your home dir being on the network is immaterial since once meshed with the OS on login it appears as a local filesystem. Like Linux, Windows, OS X, FreeBSD, and a myriad of other OSs do.

Comment: I apologize, there are many linux packages that follow the `./configure --prefix=` convention that set my expectations; I never suspected they were doing it _wrong_ all these years. So rvm MUST be installed to /usr/local/rvm, no exceptions. Fine, but this is not what the current docs say.

Comment: Whatever, we aren;t installing in a root directory, we're installing in the FHSv2.2 and other hierarchy specifications for OSs. Anyways, set rvm_prefix and go to town. But can your attitude. Not going to deal with someone who acts like being snotty is the way to get help. I've other people to help than waste it on attitude. The check is in the mail for your refund.

Comment: Well, your help had a bit of an angry tone to start with didn't it?  The real problem was a stupid CRLF config on my end, so I'm sorry I didn't catch it sooner. We got off to a bad start because you assumed I was doing something undocumented and unsupported [instead of reading your own docs](http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/): "Have RVM install to a different location (notice that it ends with /rvm): `rvm_path=/opt/rvm`"  As for rvm, I use it daily and greatly value the contributions to the project.  Sorry I was snarky.

Comment: thats fine. but i see you've modified your original statement and added stuff that wasn't there before which, had it been there would have changed the response. but sine you're done, its not a big deal now. i'm done.